# Where to create HostBuilder and avoid 'The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data'

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I took a legacy .NET framework application, that consisted of class libraries and a unit test project only, and converted them all to .NET core 3.1.

I can't seem to execute or bootstrap the unit tests with the .NET core method of using the `IHostBuilder`'s  `CreateHostBuilder`.

When I debug any of my unit tests, it stops executing and I get this error:

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: IOptions`1 appConfig, IServiceX serviceX, ITemplateEngine templateEngine   Exception doesn't have a stacktrace

Sample unit test:

```
public class TemplateGenerationTests : BaseTest
{
    private readonly AppConfiguration appConfig;
    private readonly IServiceX serviceX;
    private readonly ITemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public TemplateGenerationTests(IOptions<AppConfiguration> appConfig, IServiceX serviceX, ITemplateEngine templateEngine)
    {
        this.appConfig = appConfig.Value;
        this.serviceX = serviceX;
        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SomeTestIhave()
    {
        //removed for brevity
        serviceX.DoWork(appConfig.SomeAppProp);
        

        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.NotEmpty(result);
    }
}
```

Base class (I have a feeling this is the incorrect way of creating the hostbuiler):

```
public class BaseTest
{
    public BaseTest()
    {
        var builder = CreateHostBuilder();
        Task.Run(() => builder.RunConsoleAsync());
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args = null) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                if (args != null)
                {
                    config.AddCommandLine(args);
                }
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddOptions();
                services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration"));
                
                services.AddTransient<IServiceX, ServiceX>();
                services.AddTransient<ITemplateEngine, TemplateEngine>();
                
                //removed for brevity..
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
            });
}
```

Ideally, I am looking for a single point where I can setup the `HostBuilder` i.e. in a console or API .NET project, this would be in the `Main` method of the `Program` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the small modification you can get rid of injecting services into `TemplateGenerationTests` class:

The `BaseTest` class:

```
public class BaseTest
{
    public BaseTest()
    {
        TestHost = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
        Task.Run(() => TestHost.RunAsync());
    }

    public IHost TestHost { get; }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args = null) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                if (args != null)
                {
                    config.AddCommandLine(args);
                }
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddOptions();
                services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration"));

                services.AddTransient<IServiceX, ServiceX>();
                services.AddTransient<ITemplateEngine, TemplateEngine>();

                //removed for brevity..
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
            });
}
```

And the `TemplateGenerationTests` class:

```
public class TemplateGenerationTests : IClassFixture<BaseTest>
{
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public TemplateGenerationTests(BaseTest baseTest)
    {
        _host = baseTest.TestHost;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SomeTestIhave()
    {
        // Arrange
        var serviceX = _host.Services.GetService<IServiceX>();
        var appConfig = _host.Services.GetService<AppConfiguration>();

        // Act
        var result = serviceX.DoWork(appConfig.SomeAppProp);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(serviceX);
        Assert.NotEmpty(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working except for one part, the `appConfig` is not resolving and it is null.

Comment: Check the result of this line is not null `hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration")`

Comment: Yes, that was returning a null value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy the `CreateHostBuilder` method from `Program.cs` (DRY). Just set its visibility to `public` (or `internal` using `[assembly: InternalsVisibleToAttribute("Your.Test.Project")]` ) and create a little `Helper` class in `Your.Test.Project`:

```
// using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
// using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
public static T GetRequiredService<T>()
{
    IHost testHost = Program.CreateHostBuilder().Build();
    return testHost.Services.GetRequiredService<T>();
}
```

Your test class:

```
public class TemplateGenerationTests
{
    private IServiceX serviceX;
    private AppConfiguration appConfig;

    public TemplateGenerationTests()
    {
        serviceX = Helper.GetRequiredService<IServiceX>();
        appConfig = Helper.GetRequiredService<AppConfiguration>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SomeTestIhave()
    {
        // Act
        var result = serviceX.DoWork(appConfig.SomeAppProp);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(serviceX);
        Assert.NotEmpty(result);
}
```

}